# how to convert mysql query to JPQL

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

How to convert MYSQL Query to JPQL Query? Instead of converting is it possible to use same query to update entity in Java swing Program?

mysql query `select * from project.newproject; update newproject set pedate = date_add(psdate, interval duration day)`

My Entity class is showing below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "newproject")
@XmlRootElement

@Transient
 private PropertyChangeSupport changeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "pid")
    private Integer pid;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "pname")
    private String pname;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "psdate")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date psdate;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "duration")
    private int duration;
    @Column(name = "pedate")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date pedate;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed MYSQL Query as below to update selected row

```
`update newproject 
set pedate = date_add(psdate, interval duration day)
where pid = newproject.pid;`
```

and used createnativeQuery in Java to update selected row

```
Newproject_1 p = ProjectPUEntityManager.find(Newproject_1.class, 1);

ProjectPUEntityManager.getTransaction().begin();
Query query = ProjectPUEntityManager.createNativeQuery("update newproject \n" +
"set pedate = date_add(psdate, interval duration day)\n" +
"where pid = newproject.pid;");
int count = query.executeUpdate();
ProjectPUEntityManager.merge(p);
ProjectPUEntityManager.getTransaction().commit();

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Update End Date");
```